# No puedo validar campos vacios y traer un modal

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente problema tengo un formulario con varios inputs y al presionar el boton abre un modal..todo bien pero necesito que antes de abrir el modal me de un mensaje de alert  si 2 de ellos  estan vacios  y no abra este modal.

Intente con deshabilitar el boton hasta que los 2 inputs esten llenos pero al llenarlos se habilita  y al hacer click no me trae el modal   recarga la pagina y borra los datos de los inputs adjunto el codigo del formulario ...

Desde ya muchas gracias

```
<div class="card-body">
      <form  role="form" name="fr">


       <div class="col-md-4 " style="display: none;">
        <label class="control-label">IDarea:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="18" name="idarea" id="idarea" placeholder="Nombre"  value="<?php  echo $id_area ?>"  readonly>
      </div>  

       <div class="col-md-4 " style="display: none;">
        <label class="control-label">Iuser:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="18" name="iduser" id="iduser" placeholder="user"  value="<?php  echo $id_user ?>"  readonly>
      </div>  



      <div class="col-md-4 ">
       <label class="control-label">Area destino</label>
       <input type="text" maxlength="25"class="form-control" name="dest_sal" id="dest_sal" placeholder="destino" value="" required >
     </div> 


     <div class="col-md-4 ">
       <label class="control-label">Receptor:</label>
       <input type="text" maxlength="35"class="form-control" name="receptor_sal" id="receptor_sal" placeholder="Receptor" value="" required>
     </div>
```

Agregar Producto 
       
               Imprimir

**ahora agrego el codigo del modal**

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="AgregarPro" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
<h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Buscar productos</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<form class="form-horizontal">
<div class="form-group">                                              
<div class="col-sm-6">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="filtrar" placeholder="Buscar productos">
</div>
<a href="#" id="bus"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-search'></i> Buscar</a>
              </div>
                    <div class="outer_div">                                          
                                  <?php
                                    require_once('data/conexion.php');
                                    $sql = "select * from productos where id_area = '$id_area'";
                                    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                                  ?>       

                                    <table id="sampleTable" class="table table-hover table-bordered">
                                        <tbody class="buscar">    
                                    <tr  class="warning">
                                        <th>Código</th>
                                        <th>Producto</th>
                                        <th>Marca</th>  
                                        <th><span class="pull-right">Stock</span></th>
                                        <th><span class="pull-right">Cantidad</span></th>
                                        <th class='text-center' style="width: 36px;">Agregar</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <?php
                                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                                        $codigo=$row['id_producto'];
                                        $producto=$row['name'];
                                        $marca=$row['marca'];
                                        $stock=$row['stock_actual'];
                                        $cantidad=$row['precio_unidad'];                                            
                                    ?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><?php echo $codigo; ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $producto; ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $marca; ?></td>
                                        <td class='col-xs-1'>
                                            <div class="pull-right">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" style="text-align:right" id="cantidad_<?php echo $codigo ?>" value="<?php echo $stock ?>">
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class='col-xs-2'>
                                            <div class="pull-right">
                                                <input type="number"  min="0" max="<?php echo $stock ?>"  class="form-control" name= "cants" id="cants<?php echo $codigo ?>" style="text-align:right" value="">
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                         <td class='text-center'>
    <a class='btn btn-info'href="#" onclick="agregar(<?php echo $codigo ?>, $('#cants').val(), $('#receptor_sal').val(),  $('#dest_sal').val(), $('#idarea').val(), $('#iduser').val() )"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <?php    
                                    }               
                                    ?>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>

                              </div><!-- Datos ajax Final -->
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>                  
          </div>
```

**Ahora agrego la funcion que deshabilita los inputs**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 var btnEnviar = document.getElementById("add_tab");
btnEnviar.disabled = true;
var caja1 = document.getElementById("receptor_sal");
var caja2 = document.getElementById("dest_sal");
caja1.onkeyup = caja2.onkeyup = activarBoton;



function activarBoton() {
if(verificar()) {
    btnEnviar.disabled=false


}
else {
    btnEnviar.disabled=true

}
}

function verificar() {
if( caja1.value==="") 

  return false;
if (caja2.value==="")

  return false;


return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No se si estas usando `jquery`, supongo que si porque `bootstrap` lo hace, así que este es el ejemplo, espero que te sea de utilidad.

```js
function abreModal(){
  //alert('abrir');
  var dato1 =  document.getElementById("input1").value;
  var dato2 =  document.getElementById("input2").value;
  
  if(dato1.trim().length > 0 && dato2.trim().length > 0){
    //alert("Hay valores");
    $("#AgregarPro").modal('show');
  }else{
    alert("Por favor escriba datos en input 1 & input 2");
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<label>Input 1</label>
<input type="text" id="input1">
<br>
<label>Input 2</label>
<input type="text" id="input2">
<br>
<button onclick="abreModal()">Abre Modal</button>


<div class="modal fade" id="AgregarPro" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
<h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Buscar productos</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<form class="form-horizontal">
<div class="form-group">                                              
<div class="col-sm-6">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="filtrar" placeholder="Buscar productos">
</div>
<a href="#" id="bus"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-search'></i> Buscar</a>
              </div>
                    <div class="outer_div">                                          
                               Modal Ejemplo

                              </div><!-- Datos ajax Final -->
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>                  
          </div>
```

Revisa si tienes estos atributos en el botón con el que abres el modal:

```
 data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"
```

de ser así quitaselos, si aun asi sigue pasándote eso busca en tu código donde tienes la instrucción `.modal('show')`, trata de comentarlas porque te puedes estar haciendo conflicto eso, si el modal se estas abriendo por otro método.

Comment: Hola no funciona, cuando lleno un solo  input si abre el modal cuando lleno los dos no hace nada no trae el modal..tampoco muestra los mensajes

Comment: Inclusive cuando presiono el boton y los inputs estan vacios, muestra el modal

Comment: A ver, viste el ejemplo que puse?? porque allí esta funcionando, si lo aplicas igual a tu código debería funcionar, no lo crees? debes comparar código y ver que parte estas agregando de mas o de menos, yo croe que de seguro el botón que abre al modal tiene el atributo:   data-toggle="modal" data-target="#nombreDeTuModal" si es así quitaselo

Comment: Exacto ...tenes razón si  quite el atributo pero no abre el modal

Comment: Encontre el problema ....me faltaba type="button" en el boton Abre Modal...Muchas Gracias.. Cristina

Comment: Que bien, me da gusto que lo hayas podido solucionar.  Saludos